# What is a Men Delivered Word™?

Tags: pattern, wordplay, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series inaugurated by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with his original [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

Okay this should be fun and easy one. If a word adheres to a certain rule, then I call it a Men Delivered Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

[image]

In case you want it in CSV,

> Men Delivered Words™,Not Men Delivered Words™
>   selection,choice
>   cobbler,shoemaker
>   fattura,invoice
>   unit,element
>   calculator,compute
>   bulletin,news
>   behind,back
>   christmas,halloween
>   antigua,mumbai
>   proxy,surrogate
>   pluckiness,audacity

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Men Delivered Words™ or not on its own.

Comment: This is fun, but this isn't related to easy in any way =P

Comment: @Seth - Actually it is! :D Hope someone will crack it very soon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is

> For each Men Delivered Word™ either the first three letters or the last three letters are the first three letters of the name of an element of the periodic table (thanks to Scronibulus for spotting the clarification).

Examples

> Fatt**ura** ends with **ura** which starts **ura**nium. 
>  **plu**ckiness begins with **plu** which begins **plu**tonium.

Others

> **sel**ection $\rightarrow$ **sel**enium 
>  **cob**bler $\rightarrow$ **cob**alt 
>  u**nit** $\rightarrow$ **nit**rogen 
>  **cal**culator $\rightarrow$ **cal**cium 
>  bulle**tin** $\rightarrow$ **tin** 
>  beh**ind** $\rightarrow$ **ind**ium 
>  **chr**istmas $\rightarrow$ **chr**omium 
>  **ant**igua $\rightarrow$ **ant**imony 
>  pr**oxy** $\rightarrow$ **oxy**gen

They are called Men Delivered words

> This is because "Men Delivered" sounds a bit like "**Mendeleev**ered" and Mendeleev is the father of the periodic table. Also "men" is a three-letter substring of Mendeleev and is purposefully separated in the puzzle definition.

Comment: That is it! Cool! A big green tick.

Comment: Element contains MEN for Mendelevium,

Comment: @Sconibulus- Only the first 3 or last three letters of the words.

Comment: @Scronibulus Thank you for that, I hadn't noticed.

Comment: @hexomino - You can update in your answer stating only "first or last three letters of the words"